# How do I take the limit of this function?

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{3}{x-2} - \frac{6}{x^2-4}$$

I'm unable to simplify it, but when I put it into my calculator (i.ie i'll put 2.1, 2.0001, etc), I keep getting $15$.  When I try to simplify it, I get nowhere at all.  How can I make this answer be 15?

Comment: The limit does not exist.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong: when I put in $2.1$, $2.01$, $2.001$, I get $15$, $150$, $1500$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \frac{3}{x-2} - \frac{6}{x^2-4} = \frac3{x-2} - \frac{6}{(x-2)(x+2)} = \frac{3(x+2)}{(x-2)(x+2)} - \frac{6}{(x-2)(x+2)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{3(x+2)-6}{(x-2)(x+2)} = \frac{3x}{(x-2)(x+2)} = \underbrace{\frac{1}{x-2}}_{\text{This }\to\,+\infty}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{3x}{x+2}}_{\text{This }\to\,3/2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3}{x-2} - \frac{6}{x^2-4} = \frac{3}{x-2} + \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{x-2} -\frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{x+2} $$ $$= \frac{9}{2}\frac{1}{x-2} - \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{x+2} $$

Since $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+} \frac{1}{x+2} = \frac{1}{4}$$
we have $$  \lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+} \bigg( \frac{9}{2}\frac{1}{x-2} - \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{x+2} \bigg)=\infty$$